# Does rkt work on 32-bit systems?

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, 32-bit, container

I´ve learned about **rkt** on [coreos.com here](https://coreos.com/rkt/).
I am very excited about **rkt** and would like to make use of it.

**rtk** is supposed to work similarly to **docker** (virtualisation using containers)

However I´m using a 32bit-machine (Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS*). Is it possible to use **rkt** in a 32bit-environment?

Background: I´m looking for a container-based virtualisation method to start programs with a GUI (especially TeamViewer).

Answer (score 0):

> Does rkt work on 32-bit systems?

No. rkt does not even have an Ubuntu installation. There are debian installer files for Debian (rkt is in "sid" repo) so it might work on a 64-bit system. But 32? No.

1 thing that might make this possible: if the processor has a 64-bit architecture and supports hardware virtualization technologies such as "Intel VT-x"
or "AMD-V" you can install a 64-bit virtual machine and install Ubuntu 64-bit in there, and then install rkt.

Comment: Tnx Rinzwind. That´s what I wanted to know. In fact I´m running Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, 64bit as host and have Xubuntu as a virtual machine. But this one is 32bit, due to the fact that I´ve experienced difficulties running 64bit guests. What I wanted to do is install rkt within my 32bit-Xubuntu VM. Now I know that´s not possible. Tnx again.